# Can I change the default fill value used by numpy.ma?

Tags: python, numpy

I know that I can use `numpy.ma.set_fill_value()` to change the fill value of a masked array in-place. But I would like to change the default fill value so that new masked arrays will automatically use my preferred fill value. For example, for floats, I would like the output of `numpy.ma.default_fill_value(1.)` to be a value that I choose, instead of 1e20. Can this be done?

Comment: Read the `ma` code itself

Comment: All I've found is that it looks I could edit it in the source code in numpy.ma.core.py, where it defines default_filler, but unfortunately that's not an option for my use case. (I need other people to be able to use my code.)

Comment: Some `ma` methods use their own fill values.  For example `sum`  is simply `self.filled(0).sum()`.  And `prod` wills with 1..  There's also `maximum_fill_value`, and `minimum`.

Comment: I don't understand how that relates to my goal of changing the output of ma.default_fill_value(1.)